# How do I record RAM usage over time on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: docker, monitoring, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Im using the "gci" container optimised vm image running on GCP.

My program has a spike in disk reads, and I think RAM, and then crashes.

The problem is I cannot see RAM usage, only disk and CPU.

I cannot install any utilities on the "gci" vm, I can only run tools inside a Debian based container "toolbox".

How do I record RAM usage?

Answer (score 0):

There are several commands in Linux that can be used to check RAM. For example vmstat, top, free, /prox/meminfo. See this link: https://www.linux.com/blog/5-commands-check-memory-usage-linux

Comment: I was mainly wondering if there was a way I could record its usage over time in the Google Cloud Platform web UI like CPU.

Comment: You can use Stack Driver monitoring: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/. Its a log monitoring solution that integrates with AWS and Google Cloud. I think it allows monitoring RAM

Comment: The Stack Driver monitoring UI seems to only show CPU, Disk and Network. No RAM!